# Google Calendar API is sending notification to every guest instead just the new one

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I have a function in Google Apps Script that locates an event and adds a guest. It goes like this:

```
evento = Calendar.Events.get(calendarId=calendarId, eventId=configuracion['EventId'])

//Añadimos el invitado al evento.
invitados = []
if ('attendees' in evento) {
   invitados = evento['attendees']
}
invitados.push({email:respuestas['Dirección de correo electrónico']})

var recurso = {attendees: invitados}
var args = {sendUpdates: "all"}
Calendar.Events.patch(recurso, calendarId, evento.id, args);
```

The problem is that every guest is receiving a notification when a new guest is added (so, if this code is run 50 times, the first attendee gets 50 emails). If I turn the sendUpdates arg to 'none', then no one gets notified.

I want that only the new guest receives the notification email.

How can I do that?

Thanks a lot in advance,

Comment: This might be due to the `sendUpdates` parameter of your API request. It is set to `all` so every guest will receive an email notification whenever the event is updated. Have you already tried setting `sendUpdates` to `none`?

Comment: Why not just use CalendarEvent.addGuest() from [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#addGuest(String))

Comment: Because addGuest does not send email to the attendee. The whole process is that a user sends a form, and gets added to an event. CalendarEvent.addGuest includes the user in the event, but they don't get notice, so their status remains unanswered unless they actively search for the event.

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug, and now it is solved by the Google team.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/323087133